# Use a method within a view controller to call a modal view that overrides that view controller's view before it loads

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to call a HealthKit authorization function before my view appears, but it keeps appearing right AFTER the view loads which isn't what I want.  I get this error as well:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   .

(And I'm assuming the error is telling me that what I'm doing is wrong, which I am aware of.)

### Question

How exactly should I call this function to make the HealthKit authorization dialog override the view controller's view before it loads?

```
class SummaryViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var chart: CounterView!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pieChart: CounterView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

var healthData = HealthData()
let counterView = CounterView()
var scoreInt = 0

let yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

func formatDate(date:NSDate) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    return dateString
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    func healthKitAuth() {
        HealthData().authorizeHealthKit { (authorized,  error) -> Void in
            if authorized {
                print("HealthKit authorization received.")
                self.healthData.updateHealthCharacteristics()
                let seconds = 0.1
                let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
                let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

                dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.scoreInt = Int(self.healthData.score)
                    self.scoreLabel.text = String(self.scoreInt)
                    self.counterView.counter = self.scoreInt
                    self.pieChart.counter = self.counterView.counter

                    let dateString = self.formatDate(self.yesterday!)
                    self.dateLabel.text = String(dateString)
                })
            }
            else
            {
                print("HealthKit authorization denied!")
                if error != nil {
                    print("\(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    healthKitAuth()
}
}
```

Comment: You're dealing with an asynchronous closure. Your viewDidLoad will not wait for your healthKitAuth to finish its task before continuing.

Comment: you're doing something wrong with the animation for the appearance. try to turn animation off, or, **use a completion block** in the appropriate way

Comment: I know how to use a completion handler, I'm just not sure how I would load the view from one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you are getting is because you are calling up a transition in the middle of a transition. You should not try to display view controllers in the `viewWillAppear` method. (The `authorizeHealthKit` function presents a view controller...)

As for what you want... You will need to call the `authorizeHealthKit` function before your view controller loads. To do this, you may need to create a new view controller that does nothing but check for HealthKit authorization and then loads your view controller.